# BEM class names: block--hide or just hide?

Tags: bem

When using BEM naming conventions, should show and hide classes have the block as part of the name?

So if I have div.block-class and I want to hide it, should it be div.block-class.hide or div.block-class.block-class--hide ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option is correct unless you consider `hide` as a stand alone block which you mix to `block-class` (refer to https://en.bem.info/faq/#how-do-i-make-global-modifiers-for-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

The concept of hiding somethings is quite reusable across blocks. As such, it's a good candidate for a utility (See https://github.com/suitcss/suit/blob/master/doc/utilities.md). So rather than having `.panel--hide` and `.btn--hide`, you can have `<button class="btn u-hide">...</button>` and `<article class="panel u-hide">...</article>`. Hiding is an operation that can be performed on any block the very same way so rather than implementing `hide` in each block in a repetitive manner, we make `hide` its own function that operates on any block. Sort of like doing `hide(panel)` in a programming language. This keeps the blocks [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). The only time I would implement the functionality to hide within the block itself, would be if the way in which the particular block is hidden, is unique to the block itself.

It's also worth noting that 'hide' is also something that can be represented as a state (see https://github.com/suitcss/suit/blob/master/doc/naming-conventions.md#is-stateOfComponent). The convention for states is that they are prefixed with 'is-' as in `is-hidden` or `is-active`. I recommend reading http://csswizardry.com/2015/03/more-transparent-ui-code-with-namespaces/ as it gives a good explanation of how states and utilities can be used alongside blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note. While [tadatuta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33547256/747050) is perfectly correct and `hide` as a standalone block doesn't contradict rules of the BEM directly, it is a bad idea, since it will break separation of concerns most probably. Nowadays, since with recent fast development of `flexbox` and `grid` many classes define `display:` property. I.e. the result of mixing your classes with `hide` block will be dependable on the order you define your blocks in, i.e. unpredictable.

This makes hide-modifier `block-class--hide` the only reasonable solution when following BEM strictly.

It's also a good solution, due to encapsulation. Most probably you will have several ways to hide a block: `visibility:`, `display:`, `transform`, while for javascript and the rest of your application they all should mean `hidden`.

That's said, sometimes following BEM strictly may not be the best idea. That case is already considered in [ify.io](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33606902/747050)'s answer.